# I would like to loop through all the text files and insert the data to the listview

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am making an odering system program, in that program is the Order History feature, where all the text files in a folder are read through and inserted in to the ListView1.

For the ListView, I have three columns.

1. Date - which is the text file's name
2. Order - which is in the text file
3. Price - which is also in the text file

Example - Text File: "05/05/2017" < That goes to the first column. In the text file, the item and the price is split by ','. Example, "Chips,0.50"

Here's the code which works for the Date column and inserting the items and price for the first row, but not the ones after.

```
` Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\1\Tesst\Dates\"
        For Each i As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
            Dim a, b, c As String
            a = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i)
            b = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(i)
            c = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(i)
            Dim arrCheck(3) As String
            ListView1.Items.Add(a)
            For Each j As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
                Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(j)
                arrCheck = Split(text, ",")
                ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(0))
                ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(1))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class`
```

How do I make it so it works for all rows not just the first one.

[Picture Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ5Co.png)

Comment: @CallumDA thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\1\Tesst\Dates\"
        Dim arrCheck(3) As String
        Dim lineNum As Integer = -1
        For Each i As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
            Dim a, b, c As String
            a = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i)
            b = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(i) ' unused
            c = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(i)
            For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(c)
                lineNum = lineNum + 1
                ListView1.Items.Add(a)
                arrCheck = Split(line, ",")
                ListView1.Items(lineNum).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(0))
                ListView1.Items(lineNum).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(1))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Shout out to @CallumDA)

Comment: @user7531258 Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\1\Tesst\Dates\"
    For Each i As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
        Dim a, b, c As String
        a = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i)
        b = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(i)
        c = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(i)
        Dim arrCheck() As String

        Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(i)
        arrCheck = Split(text, ",")


        Dim NewItem as New ListViewItem(a)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(arrCheck(0))
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(arrCheck(1))

        ListView1.Add(NewItem) 

    Next
End Sub
```